# Inherit Method not replacing the previous method Odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

so I have a module that triggers the standard module method from Odoo. When my module triggers the default Odoo method it will create an error. So I already found the cause of the error but I have difficulties replacing the method with the inherent model. This is my model and I want to replace the default _prepare_procurement_values method. I already import it too in _init.  when I debug it it stop in this line   `values = super(SaleOrderLine, self)._prepare_procurement_values(group_id)` and then it runs the old method because the error is still the same.

```
  from datetime import timedelta

from odoo import _, api, fields, models

class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.line"

    @api.multi
    def _prepare_procurement_values(self, group_id=False):
        """ Prepare specific key for moves or other components that will be created from a stock rule
        comming from a sale order line. This method could be override in order to add other custom key that could
        be used in move/po creation.
        """
        values = super(SaleOrderLine, self)._prepare_procurement_values(group_id)
        daysValue = self.customer_lead if self.customer_lead != None else 0.0
        confirmationDate = self.order_id.confirmation_date if self.order_id.confirmation_date  else datetime.datetime.now()
        self.ensure_one()
        date_planned = confirmationDate\
            + timedelta(daysValue) - timedelta(days=self.order_id.company_id.security_lead)
        values.update({
            'company_id': self.order_id.company_id,
            'group_id': group_id,
            'sale_line_id': self.id,
            'date_planned': date_planned,
            'route_ids': self.route_id,
            'warehouse_id': self.order_id.warehouse_id or False,
            'partner_id': self.order_id.partner_shipping_id.id,
        })
        for line in self.filtered("order_id.commitment_date"):
            date_planned = fields.Datetime.from_string(line.order_id.commitment_date) - timedelta(days=line.order_id.company_id.security_lead)
            values.update({
                'date_planned': fields.Datetime.to_string(date_planned),
            })
        return values
```

the error

```
     File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\addons\hotel_restaurant\models\sale_order_line.py", line 14, in _prepare_procurement_values
    values = super(SaleOrderLine, self)._prepare_procurement_values(group_id)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\sale_stock\models\sale_order.py", line 337, in _prepare_procurement_values
    + timedelta(days=self.customer_lead or 0.0) - timedelta(days=self.order_id.company_id.security_lead)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: There is no value in `self.order_id.confirmation_date` that's why

Comment: @PruthviBarot yea you right it has no value, so I change it and add a condition if there is no value it will use DateTime now.  But I still don't understand why it still triggering the old method, because after I change it the error is still thrown from the default method

Comment: When you call super in your method, first it will execute the main method(old) then yours. If you don't want to execute old method then remove super call from your method

Comment: Make sure to add `sale` in `depends` of `__manifest__` of your custom module. Otherwise, it may skip your custom inherited method.